# Condition with multiple logical operators on a single variable without repeating variable name

Tags: c#

Looking at the following `if` statement:

```
var veryLongVariableName = 7;
if (veryLongVariableName > 5 && veryLongVariableName < 18 && veryLongVariableName != 13)
{
    //do something...
}
```

Is there way to write this in a simpler way, so variable name would be not get repeated 3 times inside of `if` expression? I am looking for a solution that would also work for other value types/reference types.

Comment: Pattern matching?:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using C#9, you can use `and`:

```
var veryLongVariableName = 7;
if (veryLongVariableName is > 5 and < 18 and not 13)
{
    //do something...
}
```

Because you are checking against constant values, you can create a [logical pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns), which uses `is` followed by `and`, `or` and `not`.

This also uses [relational patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#relational-patterns) (with the `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` operators); another C#9 pattern matching enhancement.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'not 13' instead of '!= 13' ?

Comment: @RaceRalph Yes, that's right.